# Adding a Radio button from one PHP form to another PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

Basically, I have two form, a UserForm and AdminForm.
On the AdminForm, I want to have a text field in which the admin can type in a new charity and then that new charity will be added to the UserForm charity_list as a new value, though I am not sure how to that and it is the last part of my code.

This is where i want to add the the radio button on the userForm:

```
      <font size ="5" >Pick Your Charity</font>
  <br><br>
  <input type ="radio" id="1" value="1" name="charity_list">Street2Feet
  <br>
  <input type ="radio" id="2" value="2" name="charity_list">The Good Project
```

here is where i was trying to do it on admin form:

```
     <form method="post" action = "UserForm.php" >

     <input type="submit" name="Insert" value="Add New Charity">
```

Can someone please help? if there is too much information, let me know

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you're trying to do is the Admin Form act as simple CMS where the admin can add the Charity List and display it in the User Form.

Here what you should you do.

1) Save the value of charity added by admin in the database

2)Pull the list from database and display it in the User form (dynamically)

Comment: Well how would that work? Are thier functions for those operations already?

Comment: It will work as the charity display dynamically. I would rather suggest you to use dropdown field to pull the list of charity from the database in the User Form. Let me know if still unclear

Comment: So instead of using a radio button, use a drop down menu since i assume it would be easier to bring it from the database and display it on the user form so the next time a user sees the form, that will appear on it, if i understand correctly

Comment: Yupp. But the most important is the Admin Form to store the charity values in database.